# Draw shape of land on view by taking latitude and longitude in iOS?

Tags: ios, latitude-longitude, drawrect

I want to draw shape of small land on view by taking latitude and longitude at the corner of land.

I have wrote following code. For now I took hard core values.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size;
SCALE = MIN(screenSize.width, screenSize.height) / (2.0 * EARTH_RADIUS);
OFFSET = MIN(screenSize.width, screenSize.height) / 2.0;

CGPoint latLong1 = {18.626103, 73.805023};
CGPoint latLong2 = {18.626444, 73.804884};
CGPoint latLong3 = {18.626226, 73.804969};
CGPoint latLong4 = {18.626103, 73.805023};

 NSMutableArray *points=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self convertLatLongCoord:latLong1]],[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self convertLatLongCoord:latLong2]], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self convertLatLongCoord:latLong3]],[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[self convertLatLongCoord:latLong4]],nil];

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   for(int i=0;i<points.count;i++)
   {

      // CGPoint newCoord = [self convertLatLongCoord:latLong];

       NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:i];
       CGPoint newCoord = [val CGPointValue];

       if(i == 0)
      {
          // move to the first point
          CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, newCoord.x, newCoord.y);
      }
      else
      {
          CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, newCoord.x, newCoord.y);

          CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1);

          CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
      }        
   } 
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Below is method which converts lat long into x,y co-ordinates.

```
- (CGPoint)convertLatLongCoord:(CGPoint)latLong 
  {

     CGFloat x = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(latLong.x) * cos(latLong.y) * SCALE + OFFSET;

     CGFloat y = EARTH_RADIUS * cos(latLong.x) * sin(latLong.y) * SCALE + OFFSET;

     return CGPointMake(x, y);

  }
```

My problem is when I took small land(e.g house land) area lat long its shape is not visible on view after draw. How I can show maximise shape of land on view.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to use an MKMapView with which you can easily create an MKPolygon?

Comment: Is it possible.
If two lat longs are close enough then can we can add some distance between them and draw on view.

Comment: @ Anna Karenina: I want to calculate small land area. Which we can not see on map. So instead that i want to take lat long and draw shape on view then calculate area. I want to show shape of land before calculate area to user for better understanding of user.

Comment: On MKMapView or if you're drawing it yourself?  If drawing it yourself, you have to calculate the scale and offset based on the region you want to show.  All that work is done for you with MKMapView.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina: Please can you elaborate. How I can set offset and scale base on region. I am stuck form last few days.